# Choose multiple cases condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to get multipule choises after then in case statment as

```
   @value

select * from [dbo].[Currency_Tbl]

WHERE  [Currency_Active_YN]=
  CASE WHEN @value = 1 THEN 
   ( 1 or 0)
  ELSE 
     @Value = 0 then 0 
  END
```

it didn't accept the first line in col1 but accept the col2

how can I select multiple numbers after `THEN`?

Comment: A column only contains one value.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: so when `col1` is not null then do you want `0` or `1`, you cant have both

Comment: How can I have both ??

Comment: What are you trying to do????

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Update the question

Comment: @juergend updated

Comment: aaah its a where - you had it as a select. I think I know what you're trying to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `case` in `where` clauses. Use boolean logic

```
select * from [dbo].[Currency_Tbl]
WHERE (@value = 1 and [Currency_Active_YN] in (0,1))
   OR (@value = 0 and [Currency_Active_YN] = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a case to do what you're trying to do. Assuming `Currency_Active_YN` is a not null `bit` field the following logic should suffice.

```
select * from [dbo].[Currency_Tbl]
WHERE (@value=1 OR [Currency_Active_YN]=@Value)
```

Comment: Nicely reduced.